# How to override tab width in qt?

Tags: c++, qt, fonts, editor, qtextedit

I just need to know how to change the tab size in Qt in a [QTextEdit](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qtextedit.html). My Google and [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) search returned me null. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How about `tabStopWidth` property? http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qtextedit.html#tabStopWidth-prop

Comment: I rejected [the suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/22161002) by mistake, I think it's valid.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

If you want to create a source code editor using `QTextEdit`, you should first assign a fixed-width (monospace) font.  This ensures that all characters have the same width:

```
QFont font;
font.setFamily("Courier");
font.setStyleHint(QFont::Monospace);
font.setFixedPitch(true);
font.setPointSize(10);

QTextEdit* editor = new QTextEdit();
editor->setFont(font);
```

If you want to set a tab width to certain amount of spaces, as it is typically done in text editors, use `QFontMetrics` to compute the size of one space in pixels:

```
const int tabStop = 4;  // 4 characters

QFontMetrics metrics(font);
editor->setTabStopWidth(tabStop * metrics.width(' '));
```

Comment: Sadly setTabStopWidth is obsolete since Qt 5.10, see https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-5.10/qtextedit-obsolete.html

Comment: @PatrizioBekerle - looks like it has just be renamed to `tabStopDistance`? See https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-5.10/qtextedit.html#tabStopDistance-prop

Comment: Yes, @ferdinand-beyer, it looks that way.

Comment: width (of a char) is also no longer used, you can use maxWidth() instead no problem because the width is uniform

Answer (score 8):

The `QTextEdit::tabStopWidth` property might solve your problem (see [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtextedit.html#tabStopWidth-prop) for Documentation...)

Comment: thanks for your reply, to try it I set TabStopWidth to 40, so this changed my tab size. But this corresponds to 11 space characters and 5 a characters. Why all the charachters have different sizes? I want my editor to behave like source code editors. What i am missing?

Comment: Use a monospace font like Courier New and all your characters will have the same width.

Answer (score 6):

While the question about how to set tab stop width has been answered already; **computing the correct tab width in pixels** is still (or again?) an open question.

Since **Qt 5.10**, [`QTextEdit::tabStopWidth`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit-obsolete.html) is marked as obsolete and [`QTextEdit::tabStopDistance`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html#tabStopDistance-prop) was introduced. `tabStopWidth` was integer, `tabStopDistance` is `double`.

## Why so complicated?

Setting `n * QFontMetrics::width(' ')` as tab stop width makes troubles because `font_metrics.width` returns an integer. Even if you have a monospace standard font, the width of a single character is actually not an integer, so `QFontMetrics::width` returns an inaccurate measure.
If you compare the appearance of the strings `........|` and `\t\t\t\t|` (\t = tab, n=2), you will see that the pipes are not aligned properly. It will become worse the more tabs you insert.

## Solution

You could do what @Ferdinand Beyer proposed, but it will slightly change the typeface. I also had to adapt his method to make it work. However, there's a much simpler approach which exploits that you can set `tabStopDistance` now with double precision:

```
static constexpr int tab_width_char = 2;
m_text_edit->setFont(QFont("Courier", 12));
const auto font_metrics = m_text_edit->fontMetrics();

static constexpr int big_number = 1000; // arbitrary big number.
const QString test_string(" ");

// compute the size of a char in double-precision
const int single_char_width = font_metrics.width(test_string);
const int many_char_width = font_metrics.width(test_string.repeated(big_number));
const double single_char_width_double = many_char_width / double(big_number);

// set the tab stop with double precision
m_text_edit->setTabStopDistance(tab_width_char * single_char_width_double);
```

This would be so much simpler if Qt offered a way to get the width of a single character as `double`.

Comment: In at least Qt 5.15.2, I had to change font_metrics.width to font_metrics.horizontalAdvance, other than that this solution is the only one that worked for me!

Answer (score 5):

While @Ferdinand Beyer's solution will work on some systems, generally fonts are not guaranteed to have integer metrics. e.g `12pt DejaVu Sans Mono` on my Linux setup has character width of 9.625. The best solution I've found is add some letter spacing to get pixel-perfect alignment.

```
int tabstop = 4;

QFontMetricsF fm (ui->textEdit->font());
auto stopWidth = tabstop * fm.width(' ');
auto letterSpacing = (ceil(stopWidth) - stopWidth) / tabstop;

auto font = ui->textEdit->font();
font.setLetterSpacing(QFont::AbsoluteSpacing, letterSpacing);
ui->textEdit->setFont(font);

ui->textEdit->setTabStopWidth(ceil(stopWidth));
```

Answer (score 4):

Computing a product of a size of one space and num spaces is not always precise (tested under macOS, Monaco font), presumably due to some gaps in between the characters in the real string.
A better solution would be to measure the length of the string containing tabStop spaces:

```
const int tabStop = 4;  // 4 characters

QString spaces;
for (int i = 0; i < tabStop; ++i) {
    spaces += " ";
}

QFontMetrics metrics(font);
editor->setTabStopWidth(metrics.width(spaces));
```